# Get file path from TypeElement

Tags: java, kotlin, annotation-processing

I'm writing an annotation processor that generates a JSON file containing some data read from the annotations (easy) and the file path where these annotations are used.

**Problem**: I cannot figure out how to get the file corresponding to a `TypeElement` (which is the annotated element).

I found that the `TreePath` api should do this:

```
val instance = Trees.instance(processingEnv)
instance.getPath(element)
```

but it seems that `com.sun.source.util.Trees` is not available in the jdk version we use (AdoptOpenJDK OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_242-b08)

I also tried with

```
val compiler: JavaCompiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()
val fm = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null)
val locations = fm.getJavaFileObjects(element.toString())
println(locations.first().toUri())
```

but it doesn't give me a valid path to the file.

Any other hint?